# Adding unseen users to SQL database without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to scrape a forum and create a users table for every distinct user I see and it looks like this:

Table:

```
user_id (primary key), name, date_seen
```

So, if I see a new unseen user, add it to my database. If the new user is in my database already, don't add to my database.

How can I do this?

Comment: If the username or id is unique (or used as a primary key), no need to worry about duplicates because it won't let you add them. If  you're inserting multiple rows at once, you can use the INSERT IGNORE.

Comment: By inserting multiple rows at once do you mean: INSERT INTO table_name (column_list)
VALUES
    (value_list_1),
    (value_list_2),
    ...
    (value_list_n);

Comment: I don't know how you're doing your insert or where your source data is coming from (how you're scraping). Are you scraping the users into a file? Because you can import a CSV and do everything in a single line: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "filename.csv" IGNORE INTO TABLE ...... 
Or if the values are coming from another table you do an insert from a select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably by "unseen user", you mean the name and not the user id.

You can use `insert on duplicate key`.  Start with a unique index or constraint on `name:

```
create unique index unq_users_name on users(name);
```

Then:

```
insert into users (name, date_seen)
    values ($name, $date_seen)
    on duplicate key update name = values(name);
```

Note that `VALUES()` is now deprecated in favor of a slightly different syntax, but it does still work.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to "insert what's not already there" in SQL is to use
a correlated subquery to test for existence:

```
insert into users (name, date_seen)
values ($name, $date_seen)
where not exists (select 1 from users where name = $name )
```

This technique doesn't rely on any nonstandard syntax in your DBMS.